# SAS: Execute SAS code using hotkey

Tags: macros, sas, hotkeys, shortcut

I want to execute code which is *independent of my current program* via keyboard shortcuts within the Enhanced Editor in SAS 9.4 for Windows.  I've achieved this with limited success being able to execute only macro statements.  However, I want to be able to execute non-macro statements, too.  How do I do this?

Here's what I've figured out so far.

### General Setup

Get to the KEYS menu by either entering "KEYS" into the command prompt or submitting

```
dm 'keys';
```

For one of the keys, enter the definition

```
%put Hello, world!;
```

Save the new key binding by pressing `Ctrl+s`.  For the purposes of this explanation, I will bind it to `F7`.  Once saved, press `F7` and "Hello, world!" will be printed to the log.

We can extend this concept further by placing the above code in a macro.

```
%macro HelloWorld();
  %put Hello, world!;
%mend;
```

Compile the `%HelloWorld` macro.  If we then bind `%HelloWorld();` to `F7`, we can demonstrate that a macro may be called with a shortcut.

### Via AUTOCALL

We can take things further yet and save our `%HelloWorld` macro as a program `HelloWorld.sas`.  If we then put this in an `AUTOCALL` library (run `%put %sysfunc(pathname(sasautos));` to find where those are located on your computer), we can execute it within any new SAS session.

It appears, however, that only macro statements work with this method.  To demonstrate this, suppose that we instead defined `%HelloWorld` as

```
%macro HelloWorld();
  data _null_;
    put 'Hello, world!';
  run;
%mend;
```

Again, save this as `HelloWorld.sas` and place it in an AUTOCALL directory.  For me, when I try to execute this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The SAS/EIS product with which the procedure is associated is either not licensed for
       your system or the product license has expired. Please contact your SAS installation
       representative.
```

### Via %INCLUDE

Since an AUTOCALL requires a macro to be compiled and called, I thought `%INCLUDE` might execute the code directly.

Create a file called `HelloWorld.sas` containing `%put Hello, world!`. Save it to a short file path.  Then, in the KEYS menu bind `F7` to `%include "C:\Short Path\HelloWorld.sas";`.  Now `F7` will print "Hello, world!" to the log.

If we instead save

```
data _null_;
  put 'Hello, world!';
run;
```

to `HelloWorld.sas` and try to run it using our `%INCLUDE` shortcut, I receive the same error:

```
ERROR: The SAS/EIS product with which the procedure is associated is either not licensed for
       your system or the product license has expired. Please contact your SAS installation
       representative.
```

### Misc. Attempts

I've also tried entering code directly into a KEYS definition, but again, it only seems to work for macro statements.

It might be possible to use `%SYSFUNC`, but my ultimate goal is to be able to use `PROC SQL` or data steps and I don't think `%SYSFUNC` can do this.

Comment: Hi - this is interesting, but I don't see a question here.

Comment: What is unclear about it?  It certainly shows research and it is useful.  In case it's not understood how useful a solution would be, let me explain.  In the Enhanced Editor, you can create keyboard macros, but the actions allowed are limited to a fixed list proved by SAS.  However, if it's possible to execute SAS code which is independent of the current program, in the way described in the question, then the editor could be modified in ways not previously possible.  The editor would obtain scripting capabilities.

Comment: What's unclear is the question part. You spent a huge amount of time showing what you did, which is appreciated, but you don't really have enough in that first paragraph to be a clear question, at least to me.  What kind of code do you want to execute?  What's the reason/application?  These sorts of things apply to the potential answer.  (This is a fairly well covered space, by the way, once you narrow it down a bit.)  Are you trying to put utility macros in there, like you want a button for "create a format" and a button for "define a hash table"?

Comment: (cont) Or are you trying to set up your libnames automatically, or sort a dataset, or do any number of other arbitrary things.  Or further do you have some particular project-specific things you want to do (download your data, for example)?  Each of these uses has a possibly different answer.

Comment: I am trying to do any number of arbitrary things.  An ideal scripting capability would not be limited by a specific task.  While I do have a specific task in mind, it seems (perhaps naively) that it should be independent of the  process involved in executing the code performing said task.  I understand that such an ideal is not always possible with SAS.  You mention that "this is a fairly well covered space."  Do you mean in regards to using scripting to augment the editor?  If so, can you please share those resources?  I've done *extensive* research into this and come up only with scraps.

Comment: (cont) In particular, my understanding is that any scripting type ability is based on leveraging the Windowing System. How this is related to DM statements and the KEYS menu specifically I have yet to find explicitly explained. The documentation I have found is incomplete. For instance, Foxer below uses the commands `describe` and `execute`. These have not come up in any of my searches/readings. There is a particular syntax associated with `submit` (i.e. quotes) which isn't given in any documentation I've found. Yet these examples, the latter especially, appear imperative to executing scripts.

Comment: (cont) All the resources I've found essentially boil down to the
following.  Otherwise it's just odd snippets in white papers from the
1980s.
1) http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1puvpmmlcwvfqn1mvfkz3e0qvan.htm

2) http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#defaultdms.htm

3) http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n01anipwof9byln1k37tuy8nwyfn.htm

Comment: The issue with this question is that to the extent it's the broad question you pose in the comments here, it's _too_ broad.  Limited to a smaller specific subset, it would be a good question, but trying to cover the whole space it's too big for Stack Overflow - we're really trying here to answer _narrow_ questions that can be answered  in a few paragraphs at best.  Quentin's answer for example covers a part of your problem space, and is a good answer for a narrower question, but for the bigger space doesn't really cover it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the submit command, i.e. define a key as:

```
submit "data _null_ ; put 'Hello World!'; run;"
```

Also works with a macro call:

```
submit "%HelloWorld()"
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off @Quentin's answer, if your datastep is huge you can write your datastep and save it as a compiled program as such:

```
/* store your datastep (below stored in WORK, can be stored in any defined library */
data male female / pgm=work.saved_program;
    set sashelp.class;
    if SEX="M" then output male;
        else output female; 
run;
```

Then as @Quentin suggested, go to your `KEYS<DMKEYS>` window and enter:

`submit "data pgm = work.saved_program; describe; execute; run;"`

This will submit your entire datastep saved in any library you choose.