# How to create hotkey to check if variable name is valid

Tags: macros, sas

As [Robert Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) says,

> "You should name a variable using the same care with which you name a
>   first-born child."

SAS's 32 character limit can make this difficult sometimes.  It would be nice to know if a given name is valid.  Fortunately, SAS provides a function for this: [NVALID](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002271952.htm).

With this, we can construct a script that tells us whether or not our name is valid (NVALID doesn't seem to work directly in a `%PUT` statement).

```
data _null_;
  name_to_check = 'isThisAValidNameOrIsItTooLong';
  isValid = nvalid(name_to_check, 'v7');
  if isValid then put "WARNI%str(NG-) Valid name: " name_to_check;
  else put "ERR%str(OR-) Invalid name: " name_to_check;
run;
```

This could be turned into a macro.

```
%macro CheckValidity(name_to_check);
  data _null_;
    isValid = nvalid("&name_to_check", 'v7');
    if isValid then put "WARNI%str(NG-) Valid name: &name_to_check";
    else put "ERR%str(OR-) Invalid name: &name_to_check";
  run;
%mend;

%CheckValidity(IsThisAValidName?);
```

Furthermore, we could [bind this macro to a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841397/sas-execute-sas-code-using-hotkey) in the `KEYS` menu.

`submit "%CheckValidity();"`

Of course this particular binding is pretty much worthless.  That is, unless, there is a way for us to feed the function an input.

Two possibilities come to mind toward this end:

1. Bind selected text to a macro variable.  Then the selected text could be fed into the macro via `submit "%CheckValidity(&selected_text);"`
2. Somehow use the `KEYS` `paste` keyword.

I've not had any luck with either approach.

In Case 1, it's not clear how to make the Enhanced Editor self-aware.  That is, I don't know how I would go about binding selected text to a macro variable.

In Case 2, it's not clear how the `paste` keyword works, as there isn't really any documentation for it.  Whenever I use it, I get

`ERROR: You must paste into an input field.`

My questions are these:

1. Is there a way to bind selected text to a macro variable?
2. Can the `paste` command be used to paste selected text into the input of
   macro?
3. Is there another way this same task could be achieved?

Sure, this same task can be easily performed with something like AutoHotKey.  But can it be done with just SAS?

Comment: ? SAS rules for a valid variable names are pretty simple. Must start with _ or letter and contain only _, letter or digit.

Comment: How are you expecting this to function? Highlight the text, hit a FXX key and it would check? What would happen. To be honest the rules are pretty straightforward and the bottom of the editor (base) has a column indicator and the math to figure out if the start and end are 32chars long isn't difficult. In terms of bang for your buck in investing for a feature development this would be really really low on the list. You can always add it to the list as an idea though.

Comment: Yes.  Select text and, when a FXX key is pressed, pass the selected text into the `%CheckValidity()` macro.  I understand the request appears unusual.  Regardless, is such an automation possible, either through the approaches I've suggested or through some other method?